# Need Help Rails 3.2.3 -Pre-populating User data into simple_form for book resource passed into gmaps4rails to render marker into map.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, gmaps4rails

thanks for reading, I need help;

scenario: User registers onto website, entering in their "address" ex. San Francisco, CA -gmaps4rails then does it's magic & it shows in the user profile show view -user location -San Francisco.  {Not displaying map here}

Displaying map on book show.
User can upload a book -I'm using Simple_form {do I add a hidden field here with @user.address? -sorry confused, did this & it didn't work.}

So then if I put in the show view Location <%= @book.user.address %> -it shows San Francisco.

But, on the map below -nothing shows up.

How do I get the 2 to interlink?  So that people don't have to spend time filling in their location, if it's already associated with their account? 
Do I have to render an association for user address & book address for simple_form, but then how do I make that work correctly in the gmaps4rails.

Also, was looking at people using JS to render the marker, would you recommend that?
I'd like to use purely server-side though -as I want to use Ajax to submit the book form & display in an index with maybe hover over to display the map.

Looking forward to your responses, as I've been stuck on it.

Comment: you can either set the book address in the controller, or set the default value in the view ... please provide some code snippets/examples

Comment: Hey thanks =) -what snippets would you like to see?

Comment: which models have the property `acts_as_gmappable` ? I can't understand your situation. Provide: `gmaps` and `to_gmaps4rails` calls

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying -currently have a User model & Book model.
Have calls currently for both, with the gmap displaying in Book show view.
Basically, my goal is User signs up & enters their address,
address gets stored & they go to upload a book,
(This is where I get lost),
want to have a field already filled with the User.address, since Book belongs_to User.
I'm using Simple_form & when they submit, the address for the book will be the User.address & display on the Gmap.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: fixed it: @book.address = current_user.address in book controller & it displays on the map perfectly.

Comment: @MateniaRossides -if you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @apneadiving thank you so much for creating an amazing gem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the `@book` address in the controller, or set the default value in the view. eg:

```
@book.address ||= @book.user.address
```